# SAML - Service Provider in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, saml, shibboleth

I have setup Shibboleth IDP and SP. They are configured properly and are working.

I now want to remove the SP and replace it with my own code. i.e.: I want my Java code to function as the SP (routing requests, host metadata and verify SAML assertions) without running shibd.exe and httpd.exe.

Is this possible using OpenSAML? Are there any examples I can use?

Answer (score 1):

I did this using Shibboleth ECP extension.

Answer (score 0):

ECP profile is indeed a good way to achieve this. If it's all working for you then you should stick to this, I only want to point you to another possible direction.

If you still need to use Web Browser Single Sign On profile you could try integrate your code with Guanxi ([src](https://github.com/guanxi), [doc](http://codebrane.com/brane/node/10)), a Shibboleth SP Java Implementation.

But of course if you only need some lightweight Java Code to access Shibboeleth IdP then ECP is completely fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for the openSAML-java .Refer this

> https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/OSTwoUserManual